# Displaying information from Custom Fields in template with Types?

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, customization

I am trying to understand Custom Fields and how I can use them on my posts.

I have set up a Custom Field for 'author' and associated it with a template.

Now, on the PHP side of things I need to designate where the custom field's out put will be.

I have followed the documentation on the WP-Types site [here](http://wp-types.com/documentation/functions/) and so have written:

```
<p>Author: <?php   types_render_field( "author", array( ) ) ?></p>
```

But it returns nothing.

Im not sure what I've done wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Had you inquired with plugin's developers? This is rather specific to it.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. It simply required `echo` in the call.

```
<p>Author: <?php echo types_render_field( "author", array( ) ) ?></p>
```